# How do you deal with different distance based features?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, distance-functions

If I have a model where the set of features where a cosign distance measure makes sense for some of the features, and a Euclidean distance measure makes sense for the others for example using a BOW feature set with additional features like number publications made by the author, etc., how do I pick which metric I should use or split the feature set to make more sense?

Comment: How are you determining suitability? There are also other distance metrics that might be more general.